# How can be determined convergence of $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{\left(-1\right)^n\left(1!+2!+...+n!\right)}{\left(n+1\right)!}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I had exam from calculus $2$ and I could not determine convergence and absolute convergence of

> $$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{\left(-1\right)^n\left(1!+2!+...+n!\right)}{\left(n+1\right)!}$$

I tried to use linearity of sum and then use alternating series test. I am sure it is wrong. Same problem I had with absolute convergence test.

I would be grateful for any advice how to solve this problem.

Comment: have you tried the ratio test?

Comment: Do you know leibniz criteria for alternating series?

Comment: i didnt use ratio test but i will try it,i used liebniz test after using linearity after that i tried to solve limit 1!+2!+...+n!/(n+1)! but i dont know how to solve this limit as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ \frac{1!+...+n!}{(n+1)!}\geq\frac{1!+...+(n+1)!}{(n+2)!} \iff (1!+...+n!)(n+2) \geq 1!+...+(n+1)! \\ \iff  (1!+...+n!)(n+1) \geq (n+1)! \iff 1!+...+n!\geq n! $$ And this is of course always true.
This means that our sequence $a_n = \frac{1!+...+n!}{(n+1)!}$ is decreasing, and by Stolz theorem $$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n!}{(n+1)!-n!} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} = 0.$$
From Leibniz test we see that the sum is convergent conditionally. It's not convergent absolutely since $a_n\geq \frac{1}{n+1}  $.

Comment: Thanks.It seems that it was very easy.I should repeat theorems for solving limits.